# Cannot subclass ConfigurableJoint in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a configured Configurable Joint that I use relatively frequently in a Unity3d project, so I decided to implement its configuration as a subclass of ConfigurableJoint, as shown;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowJoint : ConfigurableJoint {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        this.anchor = Vector3.zero;
        this.axis = new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
        this.connectedAnchor = Vector3.zero;
        this.secondaryAxis = new Vector3 (0, 1, 0);
        xMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
        yMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
        zMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
        angularXMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Locked;
        angularYMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Locked;
        angularZMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Locked;

        linearLimitSpring.spring = 100;
        linearLimitSpring.damper = 1;
        linearLimit.limit = 0;
        linearLimit.bounciness = 0;
        linearLimit.contactDistance = 0;

    }
}
```

However, this gives me the error " FollowJoint: cannot derive from sealed type `UnityEngine.ConfigurableJoint'"

If this is impossible, why? What would be a good alternative strategy (besides instantiating a configurable joint and configuring it through code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, the problem is as it's stated:

> FollowJoint: cannot derive from sealed type `UnityEngine.ConfigurableJoint

In C#, a *sealed type* cannot be inherited.

See from [sealed (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed):

> When applied to a class, the sealed modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it.

#### How to get around this

To get around this issue, you could make a factory function, so that it's easy to recreate it:

```
public static ConfigurableJoint MakeJoint() {
    var joint = new ConfigurableJoint();

    joint.anchor = Vector3.zero;
    joint.axis = new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
    joint.connectedAnchor = Vector3.zero;
    joint.secondaryAxis = new Vector3 (0, 1, 0);

    // ...

    return joint;
}

// Use factory each time you need the same
var jointA = MakeJoint();
var jointB = MakeJoint();
```

You can also improve the factory by changing the signature of the function to take parameters, and use the arguments to set the parameters of the returned ConfigurableJoint. E.g., instead of having a fixed `secondaryAxis` this could be added so that it could be made like:

```
var joint = MakeJoint(secondaryAxis:new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
```

Read more on optional and named arguments [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Comment: I understand that it's sealed and therefore cannot be inherited from,but why was it defined as such and what would be an alternative to inheritance in this situation?

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know the motivation for why it's sealed, but one way to get around the issue would be to implement a factory pattern. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've updated, please feel free to make comments if it doesn't help

Comment: Thanks for the update, that helped. I had not considered a factory function, but it's a good idea and I appreciated the example code.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it's useful. I'd like to add that my answer is more a general C# answer and does not take Unity much into consideration (as I'm not too experienced in Unity). I see that @Programmer has made an other answer, and perhaps that is a better fit in that context. (I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 2):

ConfigurableJoint is a sealed classes which means that you cannot inherit from it.

ConfigurableJoint is also a component which means that you can simply accomplish what you are looking for with the `AddComponent` or `GetComponent` function which adds or gets it as a component to the GameObject the `FollowJoint` script is attached to.

*Just make a wrapper against the `ConfigurableJoint` class then inherit from that.* Use the `Awake` function to initialize variables.

**1**.If you have configured `ConfigurableJoint` in the Editor, use the `GetComponent` function to access it:

```
public class CustomConfigurableJoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected ConfigurableJoint configurableJoint;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        configurableJoint = GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();
    }
}
```

Then you can inherit from the `CustomConfigurableJoint` class and use it like this:

```
public class FollowJoint : CustomConfigurableJoint
{
    protected override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        configurableJoint.xMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
    }
}
```

---

**2**.Now, if you wish to create and configure `ConfigurableJoint` from code, use the `AddComponent` function to create new instance of it then modify it as you wish in the `Awake` function:

```
public class CustomConfigurableJoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected ConfigurableJoint configurableJoint;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        //Create it
        configurableJoint = gameObject.AddComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();

        //Modify it below 
        configurableJoint.xMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
        configurableJoint.yMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
        configurableJoint.zMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
        configurableJoint.angularXMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Locked;
        configurableJoint.angularYMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Locked;
        configurableJoint.angularZMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Locked;

    }
}
```